# Java Enum one to one to another Enum

Tags: java, enums, deadlock

I have two Enums. First:

```
public enum FirstEnum {

    FIRST(SECOND);

    private SecondEnum secondEnum;

    FirstEnum(SecondEnum secondEnum) {
        this.secondEnum = secondEnum;
    }

    public SecondEnum getSecondEnum() {
        return secondEnum;
    }
}
```

And second enum:

```
 public enum SecondEnum {

    SECOND(FIRST);

    private FirstEnum firstEnum;

    SecondEnum(FirstEnum firstEnum) {
        this.firstEnum = firstEnum;
    }

    public FirstEnum getFirstEnum() {
        return firstEnum;
    }
}
```

When i run this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("First has: " + FIRST.getSecondEnum());
    System.out.println("Second has: " + SECOND.getFirstEnum());
}
```

I have this result:

```
First has: SECOND
Second has: null
```

If i change the lines - it will be vice versa.
I understand that there is may be some like deadlock, but what can i do if i really need this kind of relationship?

Comment: It's not really a deadlock, it's just a circular dependency. One solution would be to decouple them, and have a third class that can translate between them.

Comment: A deadlock would prevent your program from running and cause it to hang.

Comment: Thank you! Its really duplicate. I have not found origin question.